# RetroPie NOOBS SD card files

Tags: pi-3b+, noobs, retropie

A while ago, I got a Pi with an SD card that was preloaded with noobs and RetroPie from Vilros. I've formatted the card multiple times since then and I am wondering where I can get the files again that were inside the noobs 'os' folder.

I don't want the .img or the .img.xz/.gz files since they don't really help my problem. Those are the single OS images.

I want to use NOOBS with Raspbian and RetroPie (I've manually installed it on Raspbian by itself recently, but some games are super slow and choppy with Raspbian) for separate OSs.

I've had the files before, but I wish I backed up those files when I formatted the card...

Comment: I don't see how we can know what "Vilros" wrote to the card.  Perhaps ask them?

Comment: NOOBS is dead. Look at PINN.https://github.com/procount/pinn

Comment: What do you mean it's "dead"? It's updated occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that 'Vilros' is the Pi Supplier [Vilros.com](https://vilros.com) - if not please see Joans comment above :-)

I would not use NOOBS myself but you can install it as follows:

There are two versions of NOOBS:

- Full fat - containing LibreElec and Raspbian OS
- Lite or 'network' version that does not contain any PI operating systems (such as Raspbian OS etc) and requires an internet connection to be available when used on the Pi to download a selected operating system.

1. Download the zip file from the [RPF web site here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/)
2. Check the download is correct using the sha-256 data (I use [QuickHash](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/quick-hash/id1434935486?mt=12) from the App Store but [this 'donate ware'](https://www.quickhash-gui.org) tool is cross-platform)
3. UnZip the file contents to your local drive
4. Format the SD card in FAT32 format.  You can use the operating system tools or use the SD Association format tool from [here](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/index.html)
5. Copy **all** the files and folders you unzipped in step 2 above to the root of the card maintaining directory structure.  **Do not** copy the zip archive, do not change any names / file locations.

Note: In your case, you may be able to get the files after step two BUT his does not give a fully working PI - only a NOOBS installer.

Comment: Well yeah, it's just noobs. I just need the booting files for RetroPie to install it alongside with Raspbian 10.